# How to generate ear file in J2EE using netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans

How to generate ear file in J2EE using netbeans?
I searched on the web, but in vain. It said that I will find the ear file in dist directory in my EntrepriseApplication, but I didn't.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: are you using Maven?

Comment: No I am not using Maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a enterprise application/ear module within that application in your workspace and if you are using your build tool as `ANT/Maven`, so within `build.xml/pom.xml` if you mention your packaging as ear, as below :

```
<packaging>ear</packaging>
```

On right click of your project and do `RunAs-> Build Project(Eclipse IDE)`. It will generate the ear in your target folder of your project build path.